# Run $.getJSON but not with a callback

Tags: jquery, flask

I have the following JQuery function

```
    function StudentClicked(studentID){
        $.getJSON('/studentSelected', 
               {studentID: studentID},
               function(data){
        })
    }
```

with the following app.route in flask

```
@app.route('/studentSelected', methods=['GET','POST'])
def studentSelected():
    studentID = request.args.get('studentID', 0, type=str)
```

However this function when I issue a return will be the callback function for my getJSON call in Javascript.

This is not functionality I need. I need to render_template() from the studentSelected function.

Is there perhaps anything way to send a variable from Jquery to Flask so that I don't have a callback function and I can go straight into render_template?

Or perhaps from the callback function I can make a "redirect" call appending my data object so that flask will capture it and from there I can make a render_template call?

Comment: So you just want to make a GET request to the server, and don't care what the response is? If so use [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get) instead of `$.getJSON`. Technically this should be a POST, PUT or PATCH request, not a GET, if you aren't returning data and are instead intending to have the server perform an action.

Comment: If you want to display different page why don't you simply change the page url: `location = '/my-page'`

Comment: I suppose I could use location and pass my string but I was hoping to not show this level of information on the URL bar.

Comment: In a sense I do not care of the response as I will handle the response in my python method. In fact it would be great if there was a way to POST from javascript (Jquery) for flask to capture and route without any callback function of any kind.